# Launch Intel debugger (idb) in parallel mode with MPICH and input parameters file

Tags: debugging, input, parallel-processing, mpich

I would like to launch Intel debugger `idb` in parallel mode with MPICH `mpiexec` and an input parameters textfile required by the program executable.

Launching program in normal production mode:

```
mpiexec -np 4 prog -f params.in
```

where `prog` is the name of the executable `-f` is a switch understood by the program and `params.in` is the name of the input parameters file.

My best take so far is:

```
mpiexec -np 4 xterm -e idb prog
```

This works without the input parameters file, but as soon as I supply the parameters as:

```
mpiexec -np 4 xterm -e idb prog -f params.in
```

Intel debugger breaks with the following fatal error

```
Error: ambiguous option: 'f', variants are: freshlyExceded fullname
```

Running in the standard way previously supported by `mpirun` of MPICH is not working either:

```
mpirun -dbg=idb -np N [other mpich options] \
application [application arguments] [-idb idb options]
```

Neither `mpirun` nor `mpiexec` do not accept the `-gdb` switch.

Intel debugger version 13.0, Build [80.483.23]

MPICH version 3.2b3

Source code is written in Fortran 90

Answer (score 1):

You've got the crux of the issue:  how do you tell a debugger that the command line arguments are for the program, not for the debugger.

For gcc, the `--args` argument is how you do this:

```
$ mpiexec -np 4 xterm -e cgdb --args ./atomicity -fname blah
```

For icc, it does not look like there is an exact equivalent.  In that case  (and this works for gdb, too), command line arguments can be given as part of the 'run' command:

```
(gdb) r -fname blah
```

this is documented in the "Intel(R) Debugger (IDB) Manual" (https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/8/4/c/5/7/6364-idb_manual.pdf)